# Adding Multiple SCNViews at different depths with same camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, scenekit, scnscene

I am programming a card game with a 3D battlefield I am adding with SceneKit.

The battlefield has a depth to it where the top of the 3D object is the top of a castle and the bottom layer is further down on the z-axis, representing the ground.

When the player has cards in their hand, I would like to draw them as UIViews at the top possible layer, I have been able to do this by adding my GameControllerView which has the UIViews of the cards as a subview, which places it directly over top of the 3D scene.

[card UI placed over top of battleground 3d scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXnDK.jpg)

I would like to draw my UIViews of cards at different depths (z-axis) within the 3D object--sometimes drawing them on a layer on the ground, sometimes drawing them on a layer on the top.

I have been able to add more 3D elements at different depths to the battleground by adding childNodes to the rootNode of my main scene, like this:

```
SCNScene *enemy_life = [SCNScene     sceneNamed:@"battle_enemy_life.dae"];
[myView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:enemy_life.rootNode];
```

but I specifically need to add UIViews and not more SCNScenes.

How can I set one SCNView at the bottom depth, draw UI Views on top of that, set another SCNView that grows to a higher z-axis depth, draw UIViews on top of that, and have them share the same camera/screen?

Answer (score 0):

I would draw the cards with SpriteKit, as opposed to UIKit.

A SceneKit scene can display a SpriteKit scene as an overlay and you can use as many sprites as you need for your cards.

Using SpriteKit with SceneKit is efficient. Using UIKit with SceneKit will make your frame rate drop.

Check SCNSceneRenderer: [overlaySKScene](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/overlaySKScene).